# Restricting Keycodes quirk in IE10 and Chrome?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, firefox, internet-explorer-10

I have a few input fields on a MVC View that I want to allow only the letters Y or N to be entered.

When I tab into these fields using Firefox (current version is 23.0.1), the value of the field is highlighted and I can type in the allowed character(s), basically overwriting the value. For example, if the value of the input is N, the N gets highlighted and I can then press Y and N gets replaced by Y. Hooray!

However, when I use Chrome or IE(10) the field is highlighted but the allowable key will not overwrite the value in the input box. The field un-highlights and the cursor is placed at the end of the value. Booo!

What am I missing?

```
//Keydown and blur events for textboxes that only allow Y, or N
$(".onlyYN").keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 89 ||
        e.keyCode === 8 ||
        e.keyCode === 9 ||
        e.keyCode === 78 ||
        e.keyCode === 13 ||
        e.keyCode === 46 ||
        e.keyCode === 16) {
        clearError(this);
        setControlValueToUpperCase(this);
        return;
    }
    markControlAsWarning(this);
    alertify.log("The " + $(this).attr('id') + " field only accepts the single characters 'Y' or 'N'");
    e.preventDefault();
}).blur(function () {
    if ($(this).val().toUpperCase() !== "Y" && $(this).val().toUpperCase() !== "N") {
        markControlAsError(this);
        alertify.error("The " + $(this).attr('id') + " field only accepts the single characters 'Y' or 'N'");
        return;
    }
    clearError(this);
    setControlValueToUpperCase(this);
});
```

Comment: you're using jQuery - use `e.which` - jQuery normalizes it so it's cross browser compatible

Comment: Thanks for the comment, however using which did not change the behavior described in my question :(

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was using the setControlValueToUpperCase() method too soon it seems. So changing my keydown first if statement to

```
if (e.keyCode === 89 ||
        e.keyCode === 8 ||
        e.keyCode === 9 ||
        e.keyCode === 78 ||
        e.keyCode === 13 ||
        e.keyCode === 46 ||
        e.keyCode === 16) {
        clearError(this);
        return;
    }
```

fixed my issue.

```
function setControlValueToUpperCase(ctrl) {
    /// <summary>
    ///     Set the contents of the control value to upper case
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ctrl">The control reference which contains value</param>
    $(ctrl).val($(ctrl).val().toUpperCase());
}
```

Horray Me!!